# What does V=(0,∞) mean?

Tags: vector-spaces

In Finite-Dimension Linear Algebra by Mark S. Gockenbach, there is an exercise which I can't understand the meaning.

It's chapter is Fields and vector spaces.

"In this exercise, we will define operation on V=(0,∞) in a nonstandard way: ..."

I want to know what V=(0,∞) means. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

This means that $V$ is the set of all numbers bigger than (and not equal to) zero. In general, the notation $G=(a,b)$ means that $G$ is the set of numbers between the number $a$ and the number $b$, not including $a$ and $b$ themselves. If we want to include the endpoints $a$ and $b$, we write $G=[a,b]$ instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I have another question. Then u, v in V are numbers, not vectors??

Comment: Yes (though it should be noted that numbers just very simple vectors).

Comment: @user323870: The elements of $V$ are numbers. They are *also* vectors, though not the sort with which we may be familiar (which is the whole point of the exercise).

Comment: Thank you! I totally understand!